# update skip locked

Tags: sql, select, sql-update, skip, locked

I have two **`SQL`** queries that I would like to combine into 1.

The first one selects rows for the update and skips those that are locked.

The second one updates the rows selected in the first query. In trying to combine those two I get the following queries but they fail. Could someone help me in finding what is wrong with the statements?

Attempt 1:

```
update table t1
set t1.value = 3
where t1.id in (
    select t2.id 
    from table t2 
    where t2.value = 3 
    for update skip locked
)
```

Attempt 2:

```
update table t1
set t1.value = 3
from (
  select t2.id
  from table t2
  where t2.value = 2
  for update skip locked
) sub
where t1.id = sub.id
```

I'm running this on an **`Oracle`** SQL Developer.

Comment: Look at the MERGE statement.

Comment: Why do you want to lock rows in table `t1` "for update" and then update completely different table `t2` ?

Comment: They are actually the same tables just different aliases.